# How to merge two halves from two pdfs in one using mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, mpdf

I created two pdf files using dompdf, but each pdf file has only half filled.
I managed to join these pdfs files into a single one using the following code:

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) {
        $source_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/boletocaixa/boleto_00000000000000" . $j . ".pdf";
        $pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($source_file);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
            $import_page = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
            $mpdf->AddPage();
            $mpdf->useTemplate($import_page);
        }
    }

    $mpdf->Output();
```

The result of the above code is a single pdf file with 2 pages, but like but as i mentioned above, the pages of this last file has only half filled, that is, i had the beggining of the first page filled and then a blank space, and the same occurs on the second page.

My goal is to create a single pdf file using the filled halves from both pdfs files. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Just do it! Nobody forces you to call `AddPage()`. The `useTemplate()` method accepts x/y values so you can place the imported pages wherever you want.

Comment: I used the x / y values ​​to position the halves in the right place in the file. The first at the top and the second in the middle of the file. It was just a matter of positioning the halves in the file. Thank you